# Estes Web Services API

Tags: php, xml, soap, estes-express-api

I am attempting to set up Estes Web Services API for the first time to add rate estimates to my website for LTL.  Most of the information makes sense.  One of my only questions is what information I put in the requestID under rateRequest?

If its something under my account on their site, where do I go to find it?

```
 <?php
    $client = new SoapClient("https://www.estes-express.com/rating/ratequote/services/RateQuoteService?wsdl");

    $request_object = array(
          "header"=>array(
          "auth"=>array(
                "user"=>"XXXXX",
                "password"=>"XXXXX",
                )
          ),
          "rateRequest"=>array(
                "requestID"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "account"=>"XXXXXX",
          ),
            "originPoint"=>array(
                "countryCode"=>"XX",
                "postalCode"=>"XXXXX",
                "city"=>"XXXXX",
                "stateProvince"=>"XX",
          ),
            "destinationPoint"=>array(
                "countryCode"=>"XX",
                "postalCode"=>"XXXXX",
          ),
          "payor"=> "X",
          "terms"=> "XXXX",
          "stackable"=> "X",
            "baseCommodities"=>array(
                "commodity"=>array(
                    "class"=>"XX",
                    "weight"=>"XXXX",
                )
            ),
        );

        $result = $client->rateRequest(array("request"=>$request_object));

        var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: From what I have found out, request ID is a random request id that I input myself.  I still have yet to get this working....unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not gotten the code to work.  But I did find that the RequestID is a variable that is set on our end.  It just allows us to connect the request to a ticket number or order number I'm assuming.

Comment: I am still attempting to get the Estes Rate Request to work.  Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912194/estes-rate-quote-php-soap-requst-returning-error